# Animate numbers using pure CSS during loading

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I manage to get this going with jQuery from many of the examples available online. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this using pure CSS without any javascript.

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9q4khw0q/)

HTML

```
<span class="count">9999</span>
```

jQuery

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

I don't mind if 9999 just rotates on page load without starting from 0. I just want to show the animation effect during the page load.

Comment: What do you mean by rotates? You could have divs containing 1-9999 then hide them, but that seems a little annoying.

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate of) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956723/css-animation-number-increment-effect/27956997#27956997?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's exactly what you are looking for, but here is an example of something similar using keyframe.

```css
div.a {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.a ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: anim 5s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  1%{
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  4% {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  5% {
    margin-top: -40px;
  }
  8% {
    margin-top: -40px;
  }
  9% {
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
  12% {
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
  13% {
    margin-top: -80px;
  }
  16% {
    margin-top: -80px;
  }
  17% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  21% {
    margin-top: -120px;
  }
  24% {
    margin-top: -120px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-top: -140px;
  }
  28% {
    margin-top: -140px;
  }
  29% {
    margin-top: -160px;
  }
  32% {
    margin-top: -160px;
  }
  33% {
    margin-top: -180px;
  }
  36% {
    margin-top: -180px;
  }
  37% {
    margin-top: -200px;
  }
  40% {
    margin-top: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm really not sure it's something you will want to create using css only :) js is pretty good for those things.

Comment: Thank you. That's a terrible way to do it. I guess i'll stick to Javascript and avoid css for this. I will mark this as correct answer.

Comment: I agree. It doesn't really makes sense (however you asked if it's possible, so the answer is "yes").

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it in CSS like in one good answer above but if it will be for big numbers like 9999 it not judicious to use CSS because you'll have to write all those numbers in your page. I think Javascript/Jquery still the better solution.